# Java applet class never found

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, chromium, java-applet

I am having a problem with the java plugins of all three major browsers: chromium, firefox and Internet Explorer. The issue is that applets will always fail to load and yield errors no matter what website or what applet I am trying to use. I can not see any of the example applets on oracle's website; I can not launch the minecraft browser applet; nor can I launch any applet across the web using any browser.

I always receive a "class not found:AppletClassHere.class" error. I know that my browser plugin must be working correctly because I can launch the Cisco Nac applet each time I connect to my network and I can launch my own simple applets offline.

I am connecting to the internet through a vpn in case that is important. It also seems like a lot of other people I know are having this issue.

Re-installing the plugin does not appear to fix the issue. I am asking this question to find out the cause of this problem, and any possible solutions.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling java?

Comment: Yes, I have. I am using the latest version of java

Comment: You mentioned a VPN.  If this is a corporate VPN, you may want to ask your IT department is it has any sort of filters on JAR files, or large file downloads.